# Error en VueJS arreglo

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js

Hola tengo un error con una función flecha

```
graficasListarEvent(){
      axios.post("/listarEventos").then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
    },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: un error 500 es un error en el evento que estas llamando.. el problema esta en listarEventos, no en la llamada....

Comment: si estas invocando un metodo post debes proporcionar los parametros, en caso de que tu endpoitn no reciba parametros pasalo a tipo GET, prueba con POSTMAN

Comment: En efecto amigos tienen razon